# React phone input number value formt issue

Tags: javascript

I have the following: ( http://catamphetamine.github.io/react-phone-number-input/ )

```
type PhoneNumberInputProps = {
  dataBdd: string
  disabled: boolean | undefined,
  label?: string,
  id: string
  onChange: any
  value: string
  error?: any
  maxLength?: number
}

const PhoneNumberInput: React.FC<PhoneNumberInputProps> = ({
  dataBdd,
  disabled,
  id,
  onChange,
  label,
  value,
  error
}) => {

  const phoneInputStyle = classNames({
    'error': error,
    'hide': disabled
  });

  const [updatedValue, setUpdatedValue] = useState(value)

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpdatedValue(value)
  }, [value])

  const DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE = 'GB'

  const handleOnChange = (val: string) => {
    setUpdatedValue(val)
    onChange(val)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Label htmlFor={id}>{label}</Label>
      <PhoneInput
        data-bdd={dataBdd}
        disabled={disabled}
        id={id}
        defaultCountry={DEFAULT_COUNTRY_VALUE}
        value={updatedValue}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        className={phoneInputStyle}
        maxLength={15}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default PhoneNumberInput;
```

if I change the value of a phone number the ui gets updated correctly and the value property gets the `+` in front of the number which is what I send to the BE.

But, if there is a default value coming from the BE and I don't change that number so it doesn't get formatted the value gets sent without the +.

Is it possible to format the value regardless of the onChange being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Format the Value before setting the state in useEffect.

```js
import PhoneInput, { formatPhoneNumber, formatPhoneNumberIntl } from 'react-phone-number-input'

<PhoneInput
  placeholder="Enter phone number"
  value={value}
  onChange={setValue}/>

National: {value && formatPhoneNumber(value)}
International: {value && formatPhoneNumberIntl(value)}
```